# discord.py fails to execute tasks.loop command

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to write a discord bot that crawls a friend's website and announces when a new post has been posted. The crawler works just fine but the issue comes when I want to announce that a new post has been posted on a specific channel. I tried announcing a message in a specific channel through the following command:

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(my_channel_id_here)
    await channel.send('hello')
```

When I run the command the message runs successfully. 
I want the script to loop every few minutes to check if something new has been posted and therefore want to stick this code into the `@tasks.loop(seconds=45.0)` section of the code. I attempted the following:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import time
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(my_channel_id_here)
    await channel.send('hello')

@tasks.loop(seconds=45.0)
async def website(bot):
    
    print("started")
        
    channel = bot.get_channel(my_channel_id_here)
    await channel.send('hello')

@website.after_loop
async def after_website():
    print('Error has caused the loop to stop!')

website.start(bot)

bot.run('')
```

When I run this, the console prints out "Started" correctly but then jumps right to "Error has caused the loop to stop!". 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your bot is ready before starting the loop:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import time
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')


@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(my_channel_id)
    await channel.send('hello')


@tasks.loop(seconds=45.0)
async def website():
    print("started")
    channel = bot.get_channel(my_channel_id)
    await channel.send('hello')


@website.before_loop
async def before_website():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()


@website.after_loop
async def after_website():
    print('Error has caused the loop to stop!')


website.start()
bot.run("")
```

[Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#recipes)